# Doctrine2 many to many not in

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities: Tax and Category.

A Tax can have many categories and a Category can be in many taxes.

This is how I have defined the categories property in my Tax entity.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\My\Bundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="taxes_categories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tax_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $categories;
```

What I'm trying to fetch is all the categories that are not associated to a particular tax.

In SQL i would do something like

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT category_id FROM taxes_categories WHERE tax_id = ?)
```

How can I make a query like that with Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the join table. Doing a join between **Category** and **Tax** will do the job. I would do the DQL query using the [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). Something like that:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select( array( 'C' ) )
    ->from( '\My\Bundle\Entity\Category', 'C' )
    ->join( 'C.taxes', 'T' )
    ->where( $qb->expr()->neq( 'T.id', ':id' ) )
    ->setParameter( 'id', $id );
```

You ask about fetching all categories, so I'd work from **Category** entity. I assume you have a **taxes** property defined in it.